# Allow comments for low reputation accounts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Does somebody see any **legitimate** reason to avoid low reputation accounts to comment OP's question ?
I personally don't see any problem if StackExchange allows already low rep accounts to post answers.

It can get absolutely counter productive when it comes to the situation where a low rep account has the opportunity to bring something really constructive to the conversation and can't do it another way than by posting an answer, knowing he may probably and unfairly get sanctioned for this... as it happened to me recently.

This situation also doesn't really welcome new contributors, and make them very inclined to run away from Stack forums, which is a lose for everybody...

Comment: AFAIK there was always a minimum limit, it was just lifted higher at some point. If not most of what you get at the comments will be "so how did you fix it?" kind of comments

Answer (score 3):

The simple reason is that spammers would abuse this and cleaning up comments is hard. Also there are less mechanics involved, which are already in place for answers. Anyway, your question is better addressed at the main meta StackExchange site.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment :) Should I remove my question from here?

Comment: @ClemC - Please don't, this is a great question. Much like WPSE - Meta is a collection of questions / answers so we can refer to them later when someone down the line has the same inquiry.